# How can I find all machines with running visual studio (2012) remote debugger?

Tags: c#, networking, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

For some automation program I make, I need to find all machines in LAN, running `Visual Studio (2012) Remote Debugger`.

I thought scanning for 4016 port on the entire subset will do, but it's very slow (two octets)...

Comment: Then you are using the wrong scanner as 65536 hosts are not a lot. In a LAN nmap & WinPcap can do this in a few minutes.

Comment: @Robert, what can I do?

Comment: Install Nmap and use it for port scanning.

Comment: @Robert, scanning 2^16 addresses is too time-consuming. The VS itself does it in a matter of 4 seconds at max. I was hoping for some kind of multicast-mechanism...

Comment: @Tap According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx the debugger sends broadcasts. Not sure if anything about the broadcasts is documented. Try Wireshark for looking into the broadcast traffic.